# How do I get an apk file from an Android device?

Tags: android, adb, apk

How do I get the apk file from an android device? Or how do I transfer the apk file from device to system?

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003462/238753 It has over 10x the number of votes and makes it super easy

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Use [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html). With *adb pull*   you can copy files from your device to your system, when the device is attached with USB.

Of course you also need the right permissions to access the directory your file is in. If not, you will need to root the device first.

---

If you find that many of the APKs are named "base.apk" you can also use this one line command to pull all the APKs off a phone you can access while renaming any "base.apk" names to the package name.  This also fixes the directory not found issue for APK paths with seemingly random characters after the name:

```bash
for i in $(adb shell pm list packages | awk -F':' '{print $2}'); do 
  adb pull "$(adb shell pm path $i | awk -F':' '{print $2}')"
  mv base.apk $i.apk &> /dev/null 
done
```

If you get "adb: error: failed to stat remote object" that indicates you don't have the needed permissions.  I ran this on a NON-rooted Moto Z2 and was able to download ALL the APKs I did not uninstall (see below) except youtube.

Comment: THanks Maurits Rijk. Please assist me. I want to copy the iTwips.apk file from the device to system. I am using the following command. is it correct ? I got error "Android2.2Froyo/sdcard/iTwips.apk" does not exits...                                      /Users/bbb/Android/android-sdk-mac_86/tools/adb pull Android2.2Froyo/sdcard/iTwips.apk /Users/bbb
Thanks is advance.......

Comment: On my device (Android 2.1) the command would be "adb pull /sdcard/test.jpg" to copy test.jpg from my sd card to the current dir. Please locate your iTwips.apk file first using "adb shell". This start a shell on your device and you can use the standard Unix commands like ls and cd to browse your directories.

Comment: Hi, Actually the iTwips.apk stored in the internal memory on the device. how can I use the shell for this one? I am using the following command adp -d <devicenumber> shell .. But it does not work.. please assist me.. THanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Thank u very much. I can get the images from sdcard now. but I want to pull the apk file from device (managementApplication folder). The iTwips apk is stored on the Application folder. Please assist me.

Comment: It is possible that you don't have permissions to read from that folder. In that case you will first need root access to your device. How to do this depends on the device you have. Google device type + root access and you will probably find lots of information.

Comment: @Finder @Maurits Rijk Actually, you don't have to root the device just to pull the apk. As long as you know the full path of that apk. If the apk is installed, find the full path by first looking at the package name with `adb shell pm list packages`, and its full path `adb shell pm path your.package.name` then from your pc, you can simply `adb pull /full/path/to/your.apk`

Comment: For instructions, see answer from Yojimbo.

Comment: On Linux, I actually had to strip the CR first (or the first letter was eaten): `path="${path//[$'\t\r\n']}"` (yeah, to be on the safe side I also stripped NL and tabs along; I always use this fragment for cleanup).

Comment: Worth noting that if some APKs have the same name, this will overwrite them, so you really need to do the commands specified by yojimbo instead.

Comment: any suggest using powershell,cmd or git bcs i try but no luck :(

Comment: @Steven M RHetc: Your one-line command for getting all the apks is nice, but for me it did not rename any of the "base.apk" files. What is the meaning of the snippet '2&>'? Because it seems to break the preceding mv command in bash and my google search returns only '2>&' examples. If I change '2&>' to either '2>' or '&>' (without the quotes) it works. Also, the "failed to stat remote object" errors in my case all seem related to split config apks and the multiple-line results from 'adb shell pm path' for them. I could pull all split config components by hand, so there is no permission problem.

Comment: This script run as expected but while pulling APK how to rename the APK package name with application label e.g. package name = com.example.app App display name = Example App, so how to I take back with app display name

Comment: Loop is for Unix. Write loop for Windows please. I understood what code does, but don't know what should I use instead awk.

'
for %i in (adb shell pm list packages | ???); do 
  adb pull %"(adb shell pm path $i | ???)"
done
'

Answer (score 1975):

None of these suggestions worked for me, because Android was appending a sequence number to the package name to produce the final APK file name. On more recent versions of Android (Oreo and Pie), an unpredictable random string is appended. The following sequence of commands is what worked for me on a **non-rooted device**:

1) Determine the package name of the app, e.g. "com.example.someapp". Skip this step if
you already know the package name.

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Look through the list of package names and try to find a match between the app in question and the package name. This is usually easy, but note that the package name can be completely unrelated to the app name. If you can't recognize the app from the list of package names, try finding the app in Google Play using a browser. The URL for an app in Google Play contains the package name.

2) Get the full path name of the APK file for the desired package.

```
adb shell pm path com.example.someapp
```

The output will look something like
   *package:/data/app/com.example.someapp-2.apk*
or
   *package:/data/app/com.example.someapp-nfFSVxn_CTafgra3Fr_rXQ==/base.apk*

3) Using the full path name from Step 2, pull the APK file from the Android device to the development box.

```
adb pull /data/app/com.example.someapp-2.apk path/to/desired/destination
```

Comment: I used the above to create a bash script that makes it a one-liner: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9109984

Comment: In Android 5.0, the path to the installed APK as changed to `/data/app/<package>-1/base.apk`. I've updated [my script](https://github.com/sschuberth/dev-scripts/blob/master/android/get_apk.sh) accordingly.

Comment: In order for this to work, first I had to move the app from SD storage to phone storage. The app should be listed under "/data/app/".

Comment: I was able use the terminal emulator app and fx file manager and this worked :) I was also able to use grep to search the list of packages: `pm list packages | grep NAME`

Comment: this does not work if the file is under /mnt/asec folder but it does if the file is on /data/app. Tested on a non rooted Galaxy Note 4

Comment: beginner question, once you `pull` it from the device, where is it saved to?

Comment: If the app is published on the Play Store, you can get the package name from the app page on the Play Store.

Comment: `pm list packages` supports the `-f` flag, which lists the location of the .apk for you, like `package:/data/app/com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk=com.google.android.apps.maps`. The built-in pm help is useless, but pm can also filter types of packages too, see https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#pm for more info. EDIT: just noticed that the answer below says this, but that answer isn't nearly as upvoted as this one.

Comment: Does this allow extracting the apk from a paid or "limited access" applications? I have no intentions to, just curious.

Comment: also beaware that package may NOT be same as actual app name, which is quite confusing why developers do like that.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the following error: `adb: error: remote object '/data/app/path.of.the.app-2/base.apk' does not exist`. If I browse these folders with a file browser, the folders are empty.

Comment: An easier way to get the package name is by looking up the package in google play on your pc browser. the ?id=com.publisher.appname gives away the package name, saving you browsing a huge list for the correct package name

Comment: I also found that you have to have permission set correctly on your destination machine.  I was able to run the adb pull with no apparent issues but the file never appeared. Changing the permission to full control solved that.

Comment: If anyone wants a one-liner: `adb pull $(adb shell pm path $(adb shell pm list packages | grep -i ${APP_NAME_SEARCH_TERM} | head -n 1 | cut -d ":" -f 2) | cut -d ":" -
f 2)`

Comment: I had a similar problem as @Bevor, when pulling I got the error that the apk "does not exist". I fixed it by using `adb shell` and then `cp PathToApk /sdcard/` and then copying from the sdcard.

Comment: I had a similar problem as @Bevor, this solves it by using the downloads folder as an intermediate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43157127/6067948

Comment: Works on Android 7.1.1 ; you can see the package name in the URL of the google play page for the app (if there is one).

Comment: @colin - thnx for the suggestion to first cp the .apk internally. This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: I get cannont create file/directory for any destination I try like /storage/emulated/0/Download. I don't have an SD card. Does anyone know a path that will work where I can later download to my computer?

Comment: How do you do this for split APKs?

Comment: This allows to download only base apk, I can't download the latest apk from a device

`adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.gms | findstr versionName
    versionName=22.09.20 (220300-434869283)  // desired
    versionName=21.48.13 (220304-413462841)  // base`

Comment: Worked in Samsung devices without root.

Comment: The issue @Bevor reports _most likely_ is a false error. This looks like the local shell you are using interprets the path as local on your computer, not on the device. Have a try preceding the path to the file on the device with an additional slash. So that the path starts with _two_ slashes. Then it should work.

Answer (score 151):

**No root is required:**

This code will get 3rd party packages path with the name so you can easily identify your APK

```
adb shell pm list packages -f -3
```

the output will be

> package:/data/app/XX.XX.XX.apk=YY.YY.YY

now pull that package using below code:

```
adb pull /data/app/XX.XX.XX.apk
```

if you executed above cmd in `C:>\` , then you will find that package there.

Comment: For some reason I cannot find APKs in my **/data/app/** directory.  There is always a subdirectory there.

Comment: for system apps use `-f -s` instead of `-f -3`

Comment: If you have a lot of apks, grep can help narrow down the output from the first command, if you know any word in the package name: `adb shell pm list packages -f | grep <word from package name>`

Answer (score 67):

Steps to Download APK from Device to Desktop

**A)** Make sure that your running (emulator/real Device). To check use this command

```
adb devices
```

**B)** Select all the available package list installed in your device. You can use grep command to select the specific package you intend to download.

```
adb shell pm list packages
adb shell pm list packages -f -3
```

Output (List of available packages )

```
package:/data/app/com.example.mytestapplication-sOzKi5USzfbYLPNDmaaK6g==/base.apk=com.example.mytestapplication
package:/data/app/com.example.myapplication-nd1I4FGnTZnQ9PyRbPDHhw==/base.apk=com.example.myapplication
```

**C)** Copy the package (which you like to download) from the above link. Form our case I choose this (com.example.myapplication) package

```
Syntax : adb shell pm path [your_package_name]
Command: adb shell pm path com.example.myapplication
```

Output

```
package:/data/app/com.example.myapplication-nd1I4FGnTZnQ9PyRbPDHhw==/base.apk
```

**D)** Finally, To download APK from your (emulator/real device)

```
Syntax : adb pull /data/app/[your_package_name]-1/base.apk  [your_destination_path]
Command: adb pull /data/app/com.example.myapplication-3j4CVk0Tb2gysElgjz5O6A==/base.apk /Users/$(whoami)/Documents/your_apk.apk
```

Example: Trying to pull this CertInstaller.apk file in your local machine ( Mac )

```
adb pull /system/app/CertInstaller/CertInstaller.apk /Users/$(whoami)/Documents/APK/download_apk/
```

**E)** Confirm in your local directory

```
ls -la /Users/$(whoami)/Documents/
```

Comment: The objective is to extract a single apk, yet in step 4 you pull two additional files without explanation or previous reference.

Comment: I modified this post by clarifying every step.hope this modification will be helpful and easy to understand.

Comment: Also, what's step C for? You already get the package path from `pm list packages`... You only need that if you only know the apk identifier (but not the package path).

Answer (score 60):

I've seen that many solutions to this problem either you have to root your phone or you have to install an app. Then after much googling I got this **solution for non rooted/rooted phones.**

To list which apps you got so far.

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Then you may select an app, for instance twitter

```
adb backup -apk com.twitter.android
```

**An important thing here is to not set up a password for encrypt your backup**

This is going to create a file named as backup.ap, but you still can't open it. For this you got to extract it again but using the dd command.

```
dd if=backup.ab bs=24 skip=1 | openssl zlib -d > backup.tar
```

After this all you have to do is to extract the tar content and it's done.

Hope it works for you guys

Comment: From http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/access-android-app-data-without-root.html, if your openssl doesn't have zlib, this might work:
dd if=backup.ab bs=1 skip=24 | python -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))" | tar -xvf -

Comment: This is what worked for me, not the procedure in the accepted answer. And it really helped me today when I needed APK of one of my old apps but it was not available to me other than from my phone.

Comment: Here are more information if your openssl lacks zlib support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830981/error-zlib-is-an-invalid-command

Comment: If, with @kodi 's comment you get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 1: invalid continuation byte`, then replace `python` by `python2` in the command.

Comment: On some vendors, it is impossible to backup the APK without setting a password.
Didn't work for me on the Samsung phone.

Answer (score 24):

```
C:\Users\xyz>adb shell pm list packages -f | findstr whatsapp
package:/data/app/com.whatsapp-1/base.apk=com.whatsapp

C:\Users\xyz>adb pull /data/app/com.whatsapp-1/base.apk Desktop
/data/app/com.whatsapp-1/base.apk: 1 f.... 13.8 MB/s (32803925 bytes in 
2.269s)
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward way in my opinion. Thanks!

Comment: guys using linux or mac instead of findstr use grep

Answer (score 14):

One liner which works for all Android versions:

```
adb shell 'cat `pm path com.example.name | cut -d':' -f2`' > app.apk
```

Comment: @AlexP. what did you want to tell by the link above?

Comment: In some cases `pm path com.example.name` returns multiple apk files, so this command will not work. For me the useful one was the first (named `base.apk`)

Answer (score 8):

On unix systems, you can try this function:

```
function android_pull_apk() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "You must pass a package to this function!"
        echo "Ex.: android_pull_apk \"com.android.contacts\""
        return 1
    fi

    if [ -z "$(adb shell pm list packages | grep $1)" ]; then
        echo "You are typed a invalid package!"
        return 1
    fi

    apk_path="`adb shell pm path $1 | sed -e 's/package://g' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d '[:space:]'`"
    apk_name="`adb shell basename ${apk_path} | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d '[:space:]'`"

    destination="$HOME/Documents/Android/APKs"
    mkdir -p "$destination"

    adb pull ${apk_path} ${destination}
    echo -e "\nAPK saved in \"$destination/$apk_name\""
}
```

- **Example**: `android_pull_apk com.android.contacts`
- **Note**: To identify the package: `adb shell pm list packages`

Answer (score 7):

Completing @Yojimbo 's answer, this is what I did (Linux/Mac only, will not work out of the box on Windows... maybe in git's bash shell):

```
for i in $(adb shell pm list packages -f -3 | cut -d= -f 1 | cut -d ":" -f 2); do adb pull $i; done
```

This is ugly bash, but works :)

EDIT:
It no longer works on AndroidM: all files are named "base.apk" under another dir. Should be "trivial" to fix.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one liner bash command to backup all your apps:

```bash
for package in $(adb shell pm list packages -3 | tr -d '\r' | sed 's/package://g'); do apk=$(adb shell pm path $package | tr -d '\r' | sed 's/package://g'); echo "Pulling $apk"; adb pull -p $apk "$package".apk; done
```

This command is derived from [Firelord's script](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139086/backup-all-apks-from-device-using-adb-why-this-loop-in-bash-script-doesnt-work#139099). I just renamed all apks to their package names for solving the issue with [elcuco's script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device#34174529), i.e the same `base.apk` file getting overwritten on Android 6.0 "Marshmallow" and above.

Note that this command backs up only 3rd party apps, coz I don't see the point of backing up built-in apps. But if you wanna backup system apps too, just omit the `-3` option.

Comment: @Pieter Not likely. This was tested before split APKs were common. What this script does is pull the base.apk and rename it to package name of the app.

Comment: @Pieter You'll need a modification of the script that pulls all apks from that directory and rename them in a sequence or maybe copy them to a directory.

Comment: Does it work if you just `adb install` all of the APKs for that app separately to restore it?

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212788/is-it-possible-to-merge-install-split-apk-files-aka-app-bundle-on-android-d , you've to use a new command 'adb install-multiple apk1 apk2 ...'

Answer (score 6):

As said above, you can get the apk by using the pull command in adb.

Since, you are talking about your installed applications, go ahead and look in the **/data/app** directory of your Android filesystem. You will find the APK's there.

Then use the adb command - adb pull /data/data/appname.apk

Answer (score 6):

1. Open the app you wish to extract the apk from on your phone.
2. Get the currently opened app with:

   ```
   adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedActivity
   ```
3. Get the path to the package name

   ```
   adb shell pm path <packagename.apk>
   ```

4.Copy the path you got to the sdcard directory

```
    adb shell cp /data/app/<packagename.apk> /sdcard
```

5.Pull the apk

```
    adb pull /sdcard/base.apk
```

**Edit**

If step no 2 doesn't work use this:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep mCurrentFocus
```

Answer (score 6):

In June of 2023, use:

```
adb shell pm list packages --user 0
```

to list the package names, then:

```
adb shell pm path your.package.name
adb pull /data/app/your/path/to/package/foo.apk
```

to get the package(s).

Comment: got base.apk + arm64_v8a.apk + xhdpi.apk instead of single one

Comment: If there are multiple APKs, it's an Android app bundle (AAB). You get only the APKs specific to your device.

Answer (score 5):

If you know (or if you can "guess") the path to the `.apk` (it *seems* to be of the format `/data/app/com.example.someapp-{1,2,..}.apk` to , then you can just copy it from `/data/app` as well. This worked even on my non-rooted, stock Android phone.

Just use a Terminal Emulator app (such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)) and run:

```
# step 1: confirm path
ls /data/app/com.example.someapp-1.apk
# if it doesn't show up, try -2, -3. Note that globbing (using *) doesn't work here.
# step 2: copy (make sure you adapt the path to match what you discovered above)
cp /data/app/com.example.someapp-1.apk /mnt/sdcard/
```

Then you can move it from the SD-card to wherever you want (or attach it to an email etc). The last bit might be technically optional, but it makes your life a lot easier when trying to do something with the `.apk` file.

Answer (score 5):

The procedures outlined here do not work for Android 7 (Nougat) [and possibly Android 6, but I'm unable to verify]. You can't pull the .apk files directly under Nougat (unless in root mode, but that requires a rooted phone). But, you can copy the .apk to an alternate path (say /sdcard/Download) on the phone using adb shell, then you can do an adb pull from the alternate path.

Comment: The accepted answer (including the `adb shell` commands from @Isa A's comment) worked fine for me on Android 7.1.1, not rooted.

Answer (score 4):

All these answers require multiple steps for each apk file retrieved from the device.  1. determine package name, 2. find the file, and 3. download it.  I built a simple [`apk_grabber` python script](https://github.com/braebot/apk_grabber) to do this for any app that matches a given regex, and then decompiles those apks into jar files.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it:

Download and install APK Extractor in your device. It is free, and is compatible in almost all of the Android devices. Another plus point is it does not even require root or anything to work.
After you have it installed, launch it. There you will see a list of apps which are in your device, which include the apps you’ve installed later, along with the system apps. Long press any app you want to extract (you can select multiple or all apps at once), and click on the extract option you see in the top. You will also have the option to share via Bluetooth or messaging.
You’re done, you will see the extracted apps as AppName_AppPackage_AppVersionName_AppVersionCode.apk, which will be saved in the path /sdcard/ExtractedApks/ by default.

For detailed description for [how to extract apk files in android](http://appslova.com/how-to-extract-apk-files-in-android/), visit: http://appslova.com/how-to-extract-apk-files-in-android/

Answer (score 3):

I got a `does not exist error`

Here is how I make it works

```
adb shell pm list packages -f | findstr zalo
package:/data/app/com.zing.zalo-1/base.apk=com.zing.zalo

adb shell
mido:/ $ cp /data/app/com.zing.zalo-1/base.apk /sdcard/zalo.apk
mido:/ $ exit


adb pull /sdcard/zalo.apk Desktop

/sdcard/zalo.apk: 1 file pulled. 7.7 MB/s (41895394 bytes in 5.200s)
```

Comment: This helped me on a Android 7.0 Huawei device.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used code to pull .apk file from mobile but i have been using software to extract .apk file from mobile and software i have used are below with google play link:

1. [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)
2. [ASTRO Cloud & File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en)
   3.[Software Data Cable](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lyy.softdatacable&hl=en)

Hope it helps You.

Comment: I used ES File Explorer. I'm not rooted. I just went to Tools -> App Manager and long-pressed the app I wanted the APK for. This selected the app (and allowed me to select others). I think pressed the Share button and was able to send the APK to myself (using Push Bullet, but what ever works for you).

Comment: If you are not rotted then you can try App backup and restore https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup

Comment: Using ES File Explorer File Manager worked on my Nexus 6p - Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

No Root and no ADB tools required method.
Install [MyAppSharer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yschi.MyAppSharer&feature=search_result&rdid=com.yschi.MyAppSharer&pli=1#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS55c2NoaS5NeUFwcFNoYXJlciJd) app from the play store.

Comment: This App by "Jones Chi" has (as of December 2020) 10M+ downloads, 147K reviews with an average rating of 4.6, and it was last updated on November 13th, 2017, just in case anybody was wondering.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked all these answers.
Most scripts to export and rename all of them were written in Bash.
I made a small Perl script which does the same (which should work both in Perl for windows and linux, only tested on Ubuntu).

This uses ADB: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

**download-apk.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Automatically export all available installed APK's using adb
use strict;
print "Connect your device...\n";
system("adb", "wait-for-device");
open(my $OUT, '-|', 'adb', 'shell', 'pm', 'list', 'package', '-f');
my $count = 0;
while(my $line = <$OUT>) {
        $line =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
        my ($type, $path, $package) = $line =~ /^(.*?):(.*)=(.*)$/ ? ($1,$2,$3) : die('invalid line: '.$line);
        my $category = $path =~ /^\/(.*?)\// ? $1 : 'unknown';
        my $baseFile = $path =~ /\/([^\/]*)$/ ? $1 : die('Unknown basefile in path: '.$path);
        my $targetFile = "$category-$package.apk";
        print "$type $category $path $package $baseFile >> $targetFile\n";
        system("adb", "pull", $path);
        rename $baseFile, $targetFile;
}
```

1. Make sure adb(.exe) is in your path or same directory
2. Connect your phone
3. Run download-apk.pl

The output is something similar to:

```
# ./download-apk.pl
Connect your device...
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
package system /system/app/YouTube/YouTube.apk com.google.android.youtube YouTube.apk >> system-com.google.android.youtube.apk
5054 KB/s (11149871 bytes in 2.154s)
package data /data/app/com.ghostsq.commander-1/base.apk com.ghostsq.commander base.apk >> data-com.ghostsq.commander.apk
3834 KB/s (1091570 bytes in 0.278s)
package data /data/app/de.blinkt.openvpn-2/base.apk de.blinkt.openvpn base.apk >> data-de.blinkt.openvpn.apk
5608 KB/s (16739178 bytes in 2.914s)
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

wanna very, very comfortable 1 minute solution?

just you this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cvinfo.filemanager (smart file manager from google play).

tap "apps", choose one and tap "backup". it will end up on your file system in `app_backup` folder ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another bash script (i.e. will work for most unix-based systems). Based on [the answer by Pedro Rodrigues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442399/2267932), but is slightly easier to use.

Improvements over Pedro's version:

1. Original approach did not work for me on Android 7: `adb pull` kept complaining about `no such file or directory` while `adb shell` could access the file. Hence I used different approach, with temporary file.
2. When launched with no arguments, my script will just list all available packages. When partial package name is provided, it will try to guess the full package name. It will complain if there are several possible expansions.
3. I don't hardcode destination path; instead APKs are saved to current working directory.

Save this to an executable file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Obtain APK file for given package from the device connected over ADB

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Available packages: "
    adb shell pm list packages | sed 's/^package://'
    echo "You must pass a package to this function!"
    echo "Ex.: android_pull_apk \"com.android.contacts\""
    exit 1
fi

fullname=$(adb shell pm list packages | sed 's/^package://' | grep $1)
if [ -z "$fullname" ]; then
    echo "Could not find package matching $1"
    exit 1
fi
if [ $(echo "$fullname" | wc -l) -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Too many packages matched:"
    echo "$fullname"
    exit 1
fi
echo "Will fetch APK for package $fullname"

apk_path="`adb shell pm path $fullname | sed -e 's/package://g' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d '[:space:]'`"
apk_name="`basename ${apk_path} | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d '[:space:]'`"

destination="${fullname}.apk"

tmp=$(mktemp --dry-run --tmpdir=/sdcard --suffix=.apk)
adb shell cp "${apk_path}" "$tmp"
adb pull "$tmp" "$destination"
adb shell rm "$tmp"

[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo -e "\nAPK saved in \"$destination\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, using the non-rooted device Samsung Android 13 I prefer the open-source 3rd party application named "[Apk Extractor](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/axp.tool.apkextractor/)" from F-Droid as the application's usage is a one-click action and you would have extracted the APK file in the `Internal storage -> Downloads -> apk -> your_apk.apk`

Answer (score -1):

This will help for someone who is looking for a **non technical** answer

This is simple **hack**

Download the application `App Share/Send Pro` from google play store. Select the app you want to send and method send application.

I usually use Bluetooth to send applications to my pc or another phone.

Comment: It's not easy to use

Answer (score -2):

Simplest one is: 
Install "ShareIt" app on phone.
Now install shareIt app in PC or other phone.
Now from the phone, where the app is installed, open ShareIt and send.
On other phone or PC, open ShareIt and receive.