# How to get .apk file installed in Device?

Tags: android, apk

Is it possible to get .apk file installed(from market) in android device ? Please suggest me.

Comment: There is a great answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device/) for how to get an APK file from a non-rooted device.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is actually, you have to Root you phone and use Titanium Backup. I think this will allow you to backup your applications (you will get them in apk files as I remember).

Answer (score 1):

You can not actually download APK files from the google play store. But you can extract apk file of an android app after installing it on an android device. See this link for more info: [Extracting apk files of android apps](http://www.tricksmatrix.com/2013/01/how-to-get-apk-files-of-android-apps.html)

The above tutorial is about creating apk files backup of any installed app on android devices.
You might find this thread useful too:
[How do I get an apk file from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use some other app in android to get apk file.
for example you can search for "AppBackup" on play sore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Possible.

You'll have to enable installations from other sources on your Android before you can download and install an APK.

**Allow APK file Instal**

1. Open your Android phone **Settings**. (Swipe down from the top of the screen, then tap the "Settings" gear icon)
2. Scroll down and tap **Apps and notifications** (Or Biometrics and security). Doing so opens the Apps and Notifications menu.
3. Tap **Install unknown apps** in the middle of the menu.
4. Select a browser. Tap the browser you want to use to download your APK files.
5. Tap the button **Allow from this source**.
6. Tap **OK** if popup message. It allows getting from unknown sources on your phone.

If you want to install an APK file directly; Now you want to get APK file in your phone storage.

1. Go, file manager and Find download apk file location. tap APK file;
2. Tap to "Allow".
3. Tap OK if popup message.

If you have Android Nougat or Oreo;

- Go Security or Lock screen and security. Tap "Unknown sources"
  button.  Confirm by tapping OK if popup message.

In addition, There have lots of alternative apps for get APK files like [Amazon App Store](https://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011&ref_=appstore_categorynav0), [GetJar](https://www.getjar.com/), Mobogenie, APKUpdater, [GetApk](https://www.getapkfile.com/), [Tap Tap APK](https://www.getapkfile.com/tap-tap-apk-download-popular-android-games/)