# Location of my apk file in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I wrote a small program in eclipse -android.Now i installed and i am running my program which is an .apk
Now i want to know where my .apk file is there and i even want to "pull" it into my system. Is it possible? If so kindly help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an apk file from an Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the apk to install on a phone or similar use File -> Export -> Android Application

Comment: Upvoted because this is the best way to do this, but I did have to generate a key file -- a bunch of steps to go through.  If I had the path to the apk then I can just copy it to my device since it uses the debug key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes should be possible. Do a `adb shell` and look under /data/apps (e.g. ls /data/apps). Once you know the filename you can do `adb pull filename .`

Comment: Thank you! Just what I wanted. You can also pull full paths btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can run project without make *apk*, just right click on project >> Run as >> android application.

But if you want to find *apk*, it is already in workspace/your project/bin/name.apk

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible you can also get from the ddms window into the eclipse. In the ddms select the device from the device window at left side and at right side you getting the tabbed window File Explorer, logcat, console etc.

Select File Explorer->data->app

here you getting the list of all the apk files select it and pull it by using right to top button of this File Explorer window.

see this image

[ddms view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sedg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use File Explorer within Eclipse to see all the files and folders of your emulator.