# Android get .apk file from emulator

Tags: android, apk

I am newbie to the android development. Just out of curiosity i was wondering if it is possible to get back installed .apk file from android emulator ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430078/location-of-my-apk-file-in-emulator

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app which has much more complete answers

Answer (score 4):

The question linked by @thepoosh indeed has some correct answers to your question, but it is *not* the accepted answer. Scroll down a bit to answer of either @plaisthos or @Pratik.

In short: your .apk resides in the /data/app directory on your emulator. Note: It probably has a name that differs from the name of the .apk file on your build machine, since the .apk get renamed to something that looks like your package name.

So, using adb shell:
- cd /data/app
- ls (and check the name of your .apk file)
- exit adb shell
- on commmandprompt: adb pull /data/app/your.filename.apk

Or from Eclipse use the fileexplorer tab as stated by @Pratik in the other thread.

Comment: access denied when i try to list apps in /data/app folder in adb shell how to give access for this please help me on the same

Answer (score 3):

you can copy the route if you are working in eclipse, **the apk that you install in the emulator is the same that is in your project** when you compile it, go to folder bin, select .apk ctrl+c and paste in your desktop for example.

**How to extract the apk file from device:**

First run your emulator.

if you are in windows, open cmd and go to platform-tools : in my case 
`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

after that run adb as:

```
adb pull /data/app <the directory where do you wannt to save>
```

example:

```
adb pull /data/app C:\Users\tato469\Desktop\app
```

Access this folder and select your app.

NOTE: Look if only one emulator is running, else it will throw an error.

Comment: but my concern is to get back(if possible) .apk file from emulator not from eclipse workspace.

Comment: and why do you want to do this? is the same apk.

Comment: Could give a quick edit showing how to do this on a Mac?

Comment: Hello, you can find adb in Users/your-user/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/ the next steps are the same

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to run the app on a device or do you just want the .apk?

TO run it on a device:

1) Click the project
2) Go to Run -> Run configurations -> Target tab
3) Select Always prompt to pick device then apply.

After which everytime you try and run the application it will let you select any plugged in devices

TO get the .apk

1) Right-click project file
2) Export
3) Follow instructions

Comment: i think you interpreted my question wrong. But thanks for your reply.