# Can I get APK file on phone of the installed applications

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to develop a application for backing up the files. I need to extract the APK files of installed applications like the Astro manager does.

If anyone know how to extract please give me the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get an apk file from an Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are stored in `/data/app/` but unless your phone is rooted you won't see anything there.

System apk's are stored at `/system/app`

[image: How can't you not see this OP?]

A better way of getting the exact apk path :

```
PackageManager  pm = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> pkginfolist = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
List<ApplicationInfo> appinfoList = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
for (int x = 0; x < pkginfolist .size(); x++) {             
  PackageInfo pkginfo = pkginfolist.get(x);
  pkg_path[x] = appinfoList.get(x).publicSourceDir;  
}
```

Comment: I need the apk of the applications downloaded from market. Can i get the files in /system/app - folder

Comment: You will get user apks in `/data/app`

Comment: I don't get the apk of apps downloaded from market over there (Where you point).

Comment: You can't. If you sign your apk as a system level apk, your apk will be able to see the files.

Comment: You can get the installed apps' APK files without rooting the device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app

Answer (score 1):

You need to root your phone first. Then install Android SDK. 
run adb or ddms->file explorer, look for your interested-in APK in /system/app

Comment: what do you mean by root the phone ?

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest method would be take backup of application using [ASTRO file manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en),

Open **Astro File Manager> Tool > Application Manager > Backup** [see hep docs here](http://www.metago.net/astro/fm/doc/help_tools.php).

it will backup your selected apps's .apk backup !
drop comment if any problems.