# Where can I find the .apk file on my device, when I download any app and install?

Tags: android, adb, apk

Where can I find the `.apk` file of an application on my device, which I downloaded and installed from Google Play Store. Just in case I want to send it to one of my friends through Bluetooth etc..,??

Comment: I do know of a solution that does not require your phone to be rooted!!

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device for a non-rooted solution to pulling an APK from a device.

Comment: The suggested use (send the app to a friend) is not programming related, but I definitely got this problem while developing some app. Anyway, nowadays possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is an app in google play known as [MyAppSharer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yschi.MyAppSharer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS55c2NoaS5NeUFwcFNoYXJlciJd). Open the app, search for the app that you have installed, check apk and select share. The app would take some time and build the apk. You can then close the app. The apk of the file is located in `/sdcard/MyAppSharer`

This does not require rooting your phone and works only for apps that are currently installed on your phone

Comment: how does it work?

Comment: You open the app and the UI will have you select the app you want the APK file from, and then select the method you want to use to get the file (You can email it to yourself, send the file over bluetooth, save it to an SD card, etc.). That's it. It's that simple.

Comment: I guess he meant, how does the app get the apk.

Comment: Fantastic. You are awesome sir. This enabled me to use Samsung Gear VR. Before I wasn't able to because Samsung requires me to log in, but it's impossible since their login servers are down. With this app, I could open the "sub app" oculus browser directly without having to log in through the main app. Thank you!

Comment: The link is dead now. What should we use instead of MyAppSharer?

Answer (score 28):

All user installed apks are located in /data/app/, but you can only access this if you are rooted(afaik, you can try without root and if it doesn't work, rooting isn't hard. I suggest you search xda-developers for rooting instructions)

Use Root explorer or ES File Explorer to access /data/app/ (you have to keep going "up" until you reach the root directory /, kind of like C: in windows, before you can see the data directory(folder)). In ES file explorer you must also tick a checkbox in settings to allow going up to the root directory.

When you are in there you will see all your applications apks, though they might be named strangely. Just copy the wanted .apk and paste in the sd card, after that you can copy it to your computer and when you want to install it just open the .apk in a file manager (be sure to have install from unknown sources enabled in android settings).
Even if you only want to send over bluetooth I would recommend copying it to the SD first.

PS Note that paid apps probably won't work being copied this way, since they usually check their licence online.
PPS Installing an app this way may not link it with google play(you won't see it in my apps and it won't get updates).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a file browser with an backup function, for example the [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)
Long tap a item and select create backup

Comment: Link is dead. What do you recommend now?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that I believe. It needs root permission. If you want to know where your apk files are stored, open a emulator and then go to

> DDMS>File Explorer-> you can see a directory by name "data" -> Click on it and you will see a "app" folder.

Your apks are stored there. In fact just copying a apk directly to the folder works for me with emulators.

Comment: Maybe the other answer should help you or a rooted device.