# Can't find Custom App APK

Tags: android, apk

I built my first android app a few months ago and had it installed on my phone. After a few weeks I lost the app from my Windows PC because of a new installation of Windows. Now I need the app and it still resides inside the phone but I can't seem to find the apk file anywhere! I have tried looking in the app and app-private folders and also in the data folder but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,
Owais

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get APK of installed app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app)

Comment: go to Google Play and Download super Backup take backup of your APK

Comment: Are you trying to find your apk file in your android phone? If so then there install any backup application in your phone and take a backup of your application, it will be saved in your sd card or phone memory

Comment: And this question should bot be asked here, you could ask on 'Android Enthusiast'

Answer (score 0):

If that application still installed in your device then you can get that APK definitely

Find a application on play store named apk extractor. 
It will be ask you for paid but skip it and install it, then there will be list of applications after installing apk extractor.
Just select the application for which you want apk.