# How to extract APK/App files off of emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, extract

I was trying to install a plugin for my android app, and somehow completely ruined my apps source code. I have no idea how to fix it, but I have an emulator of my app still running when it wasn't broken. My question is **how do I get the files from my emulator back into a normal project file?**

Comment: @carlpoole slightly different IMO I'm trying to access the data on the emulator

Comment: if you are just trying to retrieve the installed APK on the phone you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app but the apk itself is compiled and requires reverse engineering to get to source code.