# get APK of installed app with adb command

Tags: android, adb, apk

I try to get the APK file of installed app on my Android phone, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app) which says no need for root access.

I know Facebook app package name is `com.facebook.katana`, I see it with command `adb shell pm list package`.

Then, I tried in command line:

```
adb shell pm path com.facebook.katana
```

It returns:

```
package:/data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk
```

Then, I pull the apk file to my computer by:

```
adb pull /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk
```

But output is:

```
adb: error: remote object '/data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk' does not exist
```

Why I can not get the APK but that answer says it works?

Comment: It might be occured the devices is not rooted and this app is installed by default.

Comment: i'm not sure. this is just an assumption

Comment: btw try `adb pull /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2.apk` instead of your path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pull the APK file from the Android device to the development box by setting destination path.

```
adb pull /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk path/to/desired/destination
```

or use,

```
adb shell cat /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk > app.apk
```

Comment: are you sure the apk is not obtained? type the following line to check. las -alh

Comment: is path name com.facebook.katana itself? to check type this to see installed packages., adb shell pm list packages

Comment: adb shell cat /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk > app.apk ..try this

Comment: Tried, seems no error, but I don't know where the apk is downloaded

Answer (score 3):

Insted of

```
adb pull /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk
```

Use :

```
adb shell cat /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk > app.apk
```

And your apk will be generated inside `Your_Android_SDK_path\platform-tools`

Comment: I tried the command, looks like no error, but I can't find the apk file in platform-tools folder. Are you sure it goes there?

Comment: It turns out the apk goes to the same place  where I run the command, not platform-tools.

Comment: If your Android is not debug build `adb pull` might not work for `/app` hierarchy. So `adb shell cat` is a workaround. Also you could `adb shell cp /app/... /sdcard/x.y` and then `adb pull /sdcard/x.y` + `adb shell rm /sdcard/x.y`.

Answer (score 1):

Install MyAppSharer from Google Play on the phone, run it, find your desired app, share it to your Google Drive (or email if file is small enough).

Works on Android 7.1, where the above adb pull commands don't work (at least not for me); says app doesn't exist. So just use the app, no need to run adb commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `adb pull` to download a specified file from an emulator/device to your computer.

```
adb pull /data/app/com.facebook.katana-2/base.apk target/path
```

Comment: Please re-read the question again, It is not about 'how to install an APK'