# How to extract apk from android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

So my USB broke and I lost my android studio project. However, on the emulator, I still have my application, and I am able to run it. So my question is how do I extract my apk from this emulator.

I've read numerous threads however they were all about installation, and not extraction.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Application mentioned in this url. You should be able to do it
http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/shareit-android-apk-latest-download/