# How to get list of apk of all installed app in android device

Tags: android, apk

Where does apk files store in android device  and how to get list of  apk of all installed app

Answer (score 0):

You can not get apk file without root permission and if you would share APK file would not be good idea because of security issues.

Only good practice option is get app id and then generate Intent link to `App store` with specific package name using `App linking` like you are doing when want to start app from browser. something similar 
is here [App opening from browser](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

And here is how you can get installed apps list

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> appList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0);
```

sharing might also look like this:

```
fun shareApp(appId: String, activity: Activity) {
        ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setChooserTitle("Share app")
                .setText("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appId)
                .startChooser()
    }
```

Comment: And how to get apk from this list

Comment: Sir i am developing a share app in which I want to share app apk so how i will get those app apk

Comment: Above code will only give app name and its image but i want its apk

Comment: you can not get apk file if phone is not rooted.

Comment: So how sharing application share apps from one device to another

Comment: Sir if i get root permission of device then how will i get list of apk is there any code available on stack overflow to get list of apk after root permission

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can get the APK for most installed apps without root permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/how-do-i-get-the-apk-of-an-installed-app-without-root-access