# How to get the icon of the installed application in the Android system?

Tags: android, adb

In which folder of the Android system are the icons of the installed APKs stored in the Android system?
Is it possible to get the icon of the installed apk using adb?

I try to use adb to read the application directory but it says insufficient permissions.

Comment: is the answer below helping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps required to get an app's icon are:

1. pull the apk of the app you are interested with the [following procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013175/2442831)
2. decompile the apk using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)
3. search for the app's icon in a folder named `res`. For instance you can use the following unix command: `find . -name "ic_launcher*"`

Hope this helps