# I can't grab single characters by voice from the user in the GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

So I need to grab single characters from the user in google glass.  This is for entering passwords, captchas, spelling user names, etc.  I've tried using the sample code:

```
private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST = 0;

private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        // Do something with spokenText.
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

But it seems to try and always interpret what I'm saying as words.  It works okay for numbers, but when trying to spell characters like a password, I get random results.

Comment: Uhm. I don't know whether it's a good idea to let the user spell the password aloud. Usually a password isn't displayed on the screen since other people may read it... spelling it aloud is even worse.

Comment: Captcha spellings are my first problem, which don't have security issues.

Aloud for passwords only needs to be secure if people are listening, like in a common area, it's true that some gesture-based or head-tracking mechanism would be better like the android lock screen pattern.

Captchas are the main problem right now, but also maybe I want to spell a URL to visit.

Comment: You could go old school and use a phonetic alphabet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21251558/500681) method and passing in an array of letters, you can also run this within an activity so you could keep on the same page, just adding each letter to a view as it is heard and carry on listening until you it hears 'finish' or something similar.