# how to enable "ok glass" inside an imerssion?

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm developing a google-glass app.

How can i enable "ok glass" menu during my immersion lifetime?

I saw google maps and saw they have this "ok glass" option through-out the whole app lifetime.

Do they use internal API?

Comment: Did you read the [gdk/input/voice](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice)?

Comment: yes, but glassware is from glass timeline. I could find a way to do so from inside my app

Comment: There is a working example for this based on a decompiled .apk. Maybe you want to give this a try:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168267/glass-voice-command-nearest-match-from-given-list/21251558#21251558

Comment: thanx, then how do "Google maps app on glass" do so? is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you need would be solved by "contextual voice commands", which aren't yet available. But please follow [issue 273](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273) on our issue tracker so that you can be updated as the GDK evolves!

Comment: thanx, then how do "Google maps app on glass" do so? is there any workaround?

Comment: thanx, then how do "Google maps app on glass" do so? is there any workaround?