# call speech intent in background

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm been successful in using the webview available on glass to display inputs.

The webview allows you to pan and select links. For input fields, my users will be blocked and unable to continue following.

I was interested in using the GDK voice to translate text to speech within webview.

Is there a way to call the speech recognition intent within view or in background?

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice#starting_the_speech_recognition_activity

```
   private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: Not yet, I've asked a similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652321/how-to-navigate-a-google-glass-gdk-immersion-application-using-voice-command-onl . I'm waiting on XE14 to hopefully add it in. There's a feature request on google's site here: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is a support for `SpeechRecognizer` in the GDK. Unfortunately, this is not yet supported but a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=245) has been filed which you can follow.