# Glass GDk : Contextual voice commands without the "Ok Glass"

Tags: android, google-glass, voice-recognition, google-gdk

I have an application with a CardScrollView as activity.

```
Ok Glass => My App => Ok Glass => Next Page
                  Or  OK Glass => Previous Page
```

Would it be possible to skip the second "Ok Glass" ?

The best would be to let the Voice Command always activated but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to trigger contextual voice commands without the "ok glass" cue: the main reasons are to prevent false positive and narrow down the window when the microphone is listening for commands.

Comment: Seems legit... Also do you know if it is now possible to have more than 5 items shown in the menu list then ? Because the 5+ word are hide and I can't find a way to do custom view instead

Comment: Sorry it is not the good place to ask, I did a new question for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892612/glass-gdk-contextual-voice-command-with-more-than-5-items

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this for my Glass app.  Take a look here: https://github.com/RIVeR-Lab/google_glass_driver/tree/master/android/RobotManager/src/com/riverlab/robotmanager

You are going to be interested in the VoiceRecognitionThread, Vocabulary, and MessageListActivity.

The functionality you described is implemented in both MessageListActivity and VoiceRecognitionThread.

The vocabulary is just support for multi-layered commands. You only need to worry about it if you plan on using voice commands that could branch off to other commands. For example, in my application I was controlling a robot. Commands could look like "drive forward" "drive forward quickly" "drive forward now" or "drive forward quickly delay five".  You can see examples in the xml files here: https://github.com/RIVeR-Lab/google_glass_driver/tree/master/test

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I check a little, it seems really interesting, for  now I just wanted to know if it was a possibility proposed by the GDK, but if I really need it I will know how to find it :)

Comment: No problem! If you have any trouble understanding or reusing the code (if you need it) let me know and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to see if I can use your solution in a similarish project, but I can't get ANY voice recognition to work.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to see if I can use your solution in a similarish project, but I can't get ANY voice recognition to work. I added "test" to the connectCommands(i added some logic to avoid duplicates, becase the code was initioalizing these commands in both VoiceRecognitionThread.setup() and then in changeVocab()(called from MainActivity.onResume() resulting in duplication, I'm not sure if that's ignored. However, I cannot subsequently hit a breakpoint in onVoiceCommand(or onVoiceAmplitudeChanged). Any help would be appreciated.