# Glass GDK : Contextual voice command with more than 5 items

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am using Contextual voice command, it works great with 5 items.

But when I put more than 5 items, I can still use it by saying the words, but the UI doesn't show them.

For example if I have :

```
Next
Back
Up
Down
Cancel
Exit
```

I can say Exit and it work, but I can't see it.

Is there a way to custom the view or make it scrollable ?

Comment: The problem still exsists! Google pls fix this in XE23 :/

Comment: I am waiting for an answer that I can validate :), waiting for XE24 !

Comment: Did you already put this issue on the Glass bug tracker?

Answer (score 3):

Generally on the voice commands if you look up and down by moving your head the list will move. I'm not certain if the contextual voice commands work this way, but I'd be surprised if they didn't.

Comment: Actually I did some research and every time, there is 5 or 6 items, never more, because of this problem. There is no easy way to custom the view yet and no possibility to scroll. I guess we will have to wait next update ! Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well, that's lame! :-( I'd put a feature request into the Glass bug tracker.

Comment: Good idea, I just started so I don't have the good reflex yet :)