# Google Glass voice command send activity to background

Tags: google-glass

I do an example that launch the voice command on an activity, but when the "ok glass" shown on the bottom of the screen, the activity came to background ( it's looks like my activity goes more transparent ... )

There is a way that this doen't happen? I would like to made that ... transparent, but when I say "ok glass" not when the activity load that on the bottom ...

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to customize the Contextual Voice Command, by deleting the gray overlay above your activity.

If yes, I wanted to do the same thing but with XE19 we do not have this possibility yet.

I asked a question and got a respons with a custom solution if you are interested : 
[Custom Voice Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869216/glass-gdk-contextual-voice-commands-without-the-ok-glass)

EDIT: I also find another solution customizing the Voice Input From google, but it won't work when the XE will be upgraded : [Another Custom Voice Input](https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/tree/master/voiceMenu)