# content near "ok glass" gets grayed out

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am using contextual voice commands and I have noticed a bit weird. Content that is close to the "ok glass" text gets grayed out. The closer it is to this text, the more grayed out it gets. Since we don't have control over the "ok glass" text, I was hoping to have some text and be able to match its style so that a user could see something like  Please say "ok glass" and all of it should of course have the same text style.

I have tried to style the Please say text in many ways, but my results have been disappointing up to now. Anybody knows how to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a treatment that is placed over the window/view when "ok glass" is shown to ensure the text contrasts well with the content behind it. Unfortunately this is baked in to the platform with no way to customized it (apart from disabling contextual voice). Also since this is a global view, you will not be able to place anything over it.

Hopefully in the future contextual voice will become so ubiquitous that the "ok glass" overlay will no longer be required. Unfortunately though that is not the case today and we are left "ok glass" text with darkening background.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question and got a response with a custom solution if you are interested : [Custom Voice Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869216/glass-gdk-contextual-voice-commands-without-the-ok-glass)

I also find another solution customizing the Voice Input From google, but it won't work when the XE will be upgraded : [Another Custom Solution](https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/tree/master/voiceMenu)