# Google Glass Android : How can i use voice trigger from current Activity (to switch cards from cardscroller)

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am using a **cardscrollview** in an Activity to show text and pitcures on different cards.

Today i can scroll by using touchpad and swipe left or right but **i want to scroll between cards using voice**.

Example : when i say "next" i would like to scroll forward, and when i say "prev" i would like to scroll backwards.

I saw different answers on stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168267/glass-voice-command-nearest-match-from-given-list/21251558#21251558) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652321/how-to-navigate-a-google-glass-gdk-immersion-application-using-voice-command-onl) and it looks like you can't include GlassVoice.jar anymore (tried it but not working). I saw on google documentation that i could use Contextual voice commands but i don't really understand how to include it for my case.

I would like to have something like that :

```
if(voicetrigger == "next"){
    scrollForward();
}
```

Do you think it's possible to do ? I would be grateful if someone could help me or have ideas to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: use `voicetrigger.equals("next")` for `String` type.

Answer (score 0):

Implement contextual voice commands with menu items such as "Next" and "Previous." Once one of those items is triggered, call `setSelection(int position)` on your CardScrollView with the parameter being either the current position + 1 or -1.

Here's a sample of how I use that method in my `onMenuItemSelected`:

```
mCardScroller.setSelection(mCardScroller.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1);
```