# Speech recognition on google glass offline

Tags: java, offline, google-glass, speech

I am trying to make an offline application on google glass using the speech recognition.
Indeed, my application should understand the command "Next", said at anytime, in order to launch an action.
My application should work offline, so I would like to use a dictionnary / words list.

(Development in Java)

Are there any issues for my problem ?

Thank in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: How about CMUSphinx? http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered here already: [Glass voice command nearest match from given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168267/glass-voice-command-nearest-match-from-given-list/21251558#21251558)

more code here: https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/tree/master/hotword_detection

Comment: Thank you @pscholl, this is exactly what I needed ! You have a done a great work, congrats !

Answer (score 0):

At this point, contextual navigation is not supported. There is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273) already in place for this.

If you want to do something like this you will have to open a new card which listens to your voice input and then maybe you can perform some kind of action on the text you get. A good example would be the allthecooks app which listens for user input and processes it.

To sum it up you can't always keep listening for a voice input from user so this can be your workaround(not a feasible one though if you are looking for contextual commands).