# Are callbacks fired when the user enters or leaves contextual voice commands?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm creating an Immersion with real-time content, and to avoid confusing the user, I'd like to pause and resume updating its UI while the user is interacting with the voice menu. The problem is that `onPanelOpen()` is called when the Activity is displayed, and `onPanelClosed()` is called when the Activity finishes.

Here are the questions:

- How do I detect when the user says "ok glass"?
- How do I detect when the user dismisses the contextual voice commands without selecting a menu item or dismissing the Activity? (ex. by swiping down after saying "ok glass")

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming up against a similar problem and as far as I can tell, no callback is called on detection of 'ok, glass'. I followed steps similar to those described on this issue: [Glass voice command nearest match from given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168267/glass-voice-command-nearest-match-from-given-list) - Pull the APK mentioned (notice that it's moved location since to /system/priv-apps/) and then set up your own listener. It's certainly not an ideal situation; if you use gestures to pull up the menu instead of the voice command, various useful callbacks are triggered (onPreparePanel, onCreateOptionsMenu etc). Please share any findings if you've worked out a better solution since you posted the question!

(As for the second part (detecting the swipe down gesture), sorry I haven't tried detecting that yet)

Comment: I reported the no callback issue on https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=583&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary, please add you findings there, I guess that could help it to get noticed

Answer (score 0):

Same here, there is no callback in XE 19.1 yet.

My solution :

```
To update the menu when I need (recreate the menu) : 
getWindow().invalidatePanelMenu(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);

To catch exit of the the menu : 
Add "Cancel" in the menu, and do stuff in the onMenuItemSelected function if
Cancel is called
```