# Accuracy : glass voice command nearest match from given list

Tags: speech-recognition, google-glass, matching, google-gdk

I was following [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168267/glass-voice-command-nearest-match-from-given-list) in order to implement a speech recognizer offline using the GlassVoice.apk.

I was implementing a solution similar at this one :

```
    String[] items = {"The cat", "The dog", "The lion", "The next step"};
    mVoiceConfig = new VoiceConfig("MyVoiceConfig", items);
    mVoiceInputHelper = new VoiceInputHelper(this, new MyVoiceListener(mVoiceConfig),
    VoiceInputHelper.newUserActivityObserver(this));
```

But my problem is when I say just "cat" or "next", the speech recognizer finds the nearest word, which is "The cat" or "The next step", because the accuracy might be around 0.5.

I would like the speech recognizer not to find the nearest word but the total work.

**Is it possible to increase the accuracy (around 0.85/0.9 would be perfect)?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's a bit more accurate

```
mVoiceConfig.setSensitivity(VoiceConfig.Sensitivity.CONSERVATIVE);
```