# Google Glass, using voice to navigate / control a ListView

Tags: google-glass

I would like to use voice recognition for checking items of a ListView such as on the checklist app for plane inspection --> [Checklist app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dvmR.png). I tried to use the voice control used in "onMenuItemSelect" but unsuccessfully.

Documentation so far mentions the use of voice command on contextual menu, which is different from what I want to do. Thank you for your help

Comment: Many users seem to be fine with using VoiceInputHelper and VoiceConfig even with XE22, but when I try to implement it, it looks like I don't have the same method signatures --> VoiceInputHelper.newUserActivityObserver is absent and VoiceConfig() can receive only one String. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I am still struggling with using @pscholl examples (https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets) or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168267/glass-voice-command-nearest-match-from-given-list/21251558#21251558, I took a look at the *.jar provided in the example and VoiceInputHelper.newUserActivityObserver is also absent. Then I don't understand how it can work. Please help me :-)