# Restore source code of the app

Tags: java, android, apk

I used revert local history and now there is no code at all. I have a working version of the app on my phone.
Is there any way I can get the source code back from my phone?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/3168859)

Comment: If you reverted using your source control system (svn, git, etc), maybe your IDE has a local history you can go through? I've been able to recover deletes in both IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't get exact source code from .apk file.

You can try find your answer here.
[Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

But this will not the exact copy of your project.

Comment: why cant we get the source from apk???

Comment: @Lal we can't get exact source code from .apk file.

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/3168859)

Comment: @Lal Please read answer №3 from your link.

Comment: This is a tad misleading. Of course you can't get the source code back,  but you can get something resembling it that will certainly be a lot quicker to use than a complete rewrite. Java is a lot more amenable to decompilation than most compiled languages (assuming progard was not enabled, in which case it'll be a nightmare)

Comment: Is there anyway I can get the apk from the actual app on my phone?

Comment: @user3925417 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device