# How do I delete preinstalled apps on an android?

Tags: root

I am trying to delete preinstalled applications on my HTC phone. I have tried to root my phone but was not very successful.
Ty

Comment: Did you read the following ?  [android bloatware removal](http://www.howtogeek.com/115533/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-android-bloatware/)

Comment: @Rudy Vissers Disabling is not the same as deleting. The other option on the page is rooting which Mona clearly stated was not succesful.

Answer (score 5):

Disabling is one way. For example Motorola enables them every update.

You can also remove them completely using adb:

1. Install adb if you do not already have it, https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb
2. Enable developer mode, usually by going to settings > system > about phone > and repeatedly clicking build number
3. Configure your phone in debug mode, usually settings > systems > developer options > USB debugging
4. Start a console and put adb in your path
5. List your packages using: adb shell pm list package -f
6. Remove the package using: adb shell pm uninstall --user 0

Example:

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.microsoft.office.outlook
```

Removes Outlook

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.linkedin.android
```

Removes LinkedIn

I'm not sure if updates reinstall applications.

Source: [How do I get an apk file from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling them first from Settings and then delete app data