# Android studio - Run on phone, APK location?

Tags: android

I run the app from android studio on my phone.
Now im curious where i can find my apk on my phone.

I got countless answers on where to find the apk on the pc, but i want to know where it builds the apk on my phone.

Comment: `but i want to know where it builds the apk on my phone` , APK is build on PC,  executes or Run on Mobile...

Comment: Unless your phone is rooted, you do not have ready access to the APK location through something like the Android Device Monitor. I think that you can use `PackageManager` to find out the path to the APK, though I forget the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the apk with adb, something like:

```
adb pull /data/app/com.example.someapp-2.apk path/to/desired/destination
```

Check this question for more info: [How do I get an apk file from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

You could run this commands on console to find it:

```
adb shell pm list packages # In order to find needed package name
adb shell pm path com.yourpackage # show where is apk for package
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find apk on the your android device.

But you can use application like a "LuckyPatcher" on the android phone. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRudg.jpg)

Click on your application in LuckyPatcher->choose instrument->create Backup. Application notify about save .apk file and file path.