# Cannot pull APK from Android device with adb

Tags: adb

I'm trying to get the APK of an installed application from my device. I'm following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003462/5466997) but when pulling it, adb says the APK doesn't exist. This are the exact steps:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages
...
(whole list of packages)
...

$ adb shell pm path com.google.android.apps.books
package:/data/app/com.google.android.apps.books-1/base.apk

$ adb pull /data/app/com.google.android.apps.books-1/base.apk
adb: error: remote object '/data/app/com.google.android.apps.books-1/base.apk' does not exist
```

How can I pull this file to my local drive?

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
$ adb shell cp /data/app/com.google.android.apps.books-1/base.apk /storage/emulated/0/Download/base.apk
```

then

```
$ adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Download/base.apk
```

Comment: I'm happy to help you.

Comment: Thnx. I looked through a lot of different solutions but this is the only solution that worked for my device.

Comment: I'm happy to help you!

Comment: I get cannot create file/directory /storage/emulated/0/Download/base.apk