# How to pull apk without adb?

Tags: android, apk

I am working on an apk sharing app for which I need an apk of installed app, I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003462/7349428). which shows this command

`adb pull /data/app/com.example.someapp-2.apk path/to/desired/destination`

But when I try this on terminal in android device it shows

```
/system/bin/sh: adb not found
```

Is there any alternative command or procedure to the same on android device terminal ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without root access.

Comment: @MuratK. MyAppSharer for android does that without root.

Answer (score 0):

Use MyAppSharer, or Xender or ShareIt from app store.

Personally I use MyAppSharer to extract any installed apk. Use Bluetooth option while extracting any app.

Comment: Please read my question details. I want to know how apps like MyAppSharer extracts apk without adb pull.

Comment: I am sorry for misinformation. But no where in your question, you have mentioned about MyAppSharer. May be you should provide more details. Also write some code that you have tried.

Comment: I have added the command I tried and the error I get. Thank you!