# Can't install Galaxy store app on AWS Device Farm S10 Device

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I'm need to download an app from the galaxy store app, but I can't open the galaxy store app. It installed (as system app), but don't have a way to open it.

I tryied to install it manauly from the web. It's installed, but can't be open (and don't have any app icon in with all the other device's apps).
I do see in the settings > apps > system apps that the app installed.

Anyone know how can I get the galaxy sotre app lunache and work correctly?
Using Galaxy S10+ device on the free year plan.

Comment: how are you doing this locally? is this an automated run or a remote access run? Also would this involve you to signin to an account? This is not allowed in the public offering. 

https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faqs/

 it is recommended that you avoid providing or entering sensitive information such as account info (E.g., Google Account, Apple ID), personal information, and other security-sensitive details during your automated test and remote access sessions.

Comment: @jmp
What the meanig of "doing this locally"? This is a remote access. And offcourse I will need to sigin to an account. So you saying that only in private device I can do it?

Comment: That is recommended unless you're comfortable with risking the account in the public offering. If you forget to sign out then currently there's no guarantee that the next remote session will get the same device instance.

Comment: @jmp
Yes I know what the risk and All I agree and undrestand that my account can be used if I not sign out. So I have any way to install galaxy app store on the device?

Comment: oo okay, I thought you meant that the galaxy app store app was already installed at first. So if it's not there then you might be able to extract it from your local device and install it through Device farm's SDK. This works for me to pull apks from a device. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003462/112233

can you let me know if that helps?

Comment: @jmp
If you go to settings, section apps, you would see that you do have the galaxy app store app. But you can't open it. I tryied uninstall and upload from the upload system that amazon offers us - don't work. I tryied to uninstall and download from the web, but after the installion finshing, you can't press the open button, and there is no app icon (so I can't open it no matter what).

Answer (score 1):

AWS Device Farm does not support the Galaxy app store as a default app on Device Farm. We would recommend that you either bring your own app via an APK file or download your app from the Google Play store after logging into your Google account. If you need assistance doing these things from an automation test, please see this forums post for sample code and instructions: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=997193&#997193

Thank you,