# Extracting Cordova Assets from Phone

Tags: android, cordova

I built a Cordova app a few years ago and it looks like I no longer have the source code on my laptop. I need to update the app, but the only version of the app that exists is the one on my Android phone. It's a developer build, pushed to phone via USB cable. Is there a way to retrieve the JS/html assets from it so I can modify the app without starting to write it from scratch (the app does not rely on any Cordova plugins).

Answer (score 0):

1- You should extract the APK from your device, [here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device/4033005) on how to achieve this via ADB

2- APK files are basically a zip file, just renamed the extension and extract