# How to run Dynamic analysis by MobSF?

Tags: android, penetration-testing

I am facing problem while running Dynamic analysis by MobSF. I am using MobSF in Android Tamer VM. Genymotion is installed in Windows 10 Host machine. I can connect the android virtual device (running into Genymotion) by ADB connect. but if I run Dynamic analysis by MoBSF it is showing can not connect

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix this issue? To receive help from StackOverflow community make sure you follow [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines and that your question presents [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Are You trying to analyze an apk?

If you do, you might want to just extract the apk from your Genymotion device [using ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device),and then try to analyze the apk only.

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually I am doing automated  static & dynamic analysis on APK file by MobSF tool. I can run static analysis without any issue.but in the Dynamic analysis option of MobSF tool, I am facing connectivity problem Between MobSF tool and Genymotion Virtual Mobile device. I can connect the virtual device from the MobSF tool VM by command line. My lab set up:

Comment: Lab set up: MobSF running in Android Tamer VM
& Genymotion v3 installed in same win10 pc, virtual mobile device Lollipop running in genymotion. all are same network. if I run Dynamic analysis in MobSF, it stuck "creating environment" stage. adb connection is ok by command line from Android tamer

Comment: Hey, sure no problem I hope I can help. I just did a Dynamic analyst. I used MobSF in docker on Kali Linux VM as host ( on the virtual box ) and it runs with no issue at all. You may want to consider this solution. Please be noted that Genymotion runs on Virtual box, and I'm not sure if you are trying to sync the genymotion with VMWare, maybe try to switch for a virtual box as well.

Comment: I am using Virtual Box for syncing Genymotion. I understand from your set up as follows: MobSF need to install in Docker into Kali Linux VM. How can I sync it with Genymotion ? Do i install Genymotion into that Kali VM or into my Windows 10 host?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the dynamic analysis for apk on linux environment. I installed genymotion and mobsf using docker on linux.

Run this command:

```bash
sudo docker run -it --rm -e MOBSF_ANALYZER_IDENTIFIER=192.168.56.102:5555 -p 8080:8000 opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest
```

Sudo for permission by password. `MOBSF_ANALYZER_IDENTIFIER` is from emulator genymotion on title bar of device.

Note: Static analysis is must before dynamic analysis in mobsf