# The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature

Tags: java, android, apk, release

I have an app on the store. Unfortunately I lost all the resource files. Now I created a new project with the same package name and I used the same Keystore to generate a new signed Apk.
Now the apk is generated, but when trying to install it, I get this error:

The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?
the alias and all the passwords are correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should remove old app from your phone to install new one.

Comment: If you used google play store signing then by uploading it to the store it will be resigned by google, meaning your build will have a different signature

Comment: @mehmetsalimayan well I don't want to uninstall the old one, it's supposed to be an update.

Comment: @Quinn I have on play store and another store and both have the same problem. How do I get the google's signature?

Comment: @Keivan.k if you did use google play signing then you would need to upload the new version to the play store in order to install over the previous version

Comment: @Quinn what about other stores? they should still use the same signature created by android studio right?

Comment: @Keivan.k About Google Play Store signing see: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/09/23/uncomfortable-questions-app-signing.html and https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/11/30/initial-responses-uncomfortable-questions.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks but how doest that answer my question? I want to install a newer release version on an old one, yet can not do it

Comment: @Keivan.k sorry links were related but not specific to your problem. You should describe how you built the existing version on your phone: standard key/keystore or Google Play Signing.

Comment: @MorrisonChang No I used standard android studio signing

Comment: I would [pull the APK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003462/295004) and [check the signing key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11331469/295004) to make sure it is the same one as the new APK. I have in the past mistaken what I've installed on device (i.e. debug version vs release).